# Multiple select dropdown with unique selection - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

1. I have 4 select dropdowns.
2. Selected values should not appear on the rest of the dropdowns list

My `state` looks like this

```
this.state = {
    selectedDropdownArray: {},
    dropdownArray: ['select','1','2','3','4','5']
}
```

below is my select dropdown component

```
<SelectDropdown
    options={this.state.dropdownArray}
    value={this.getValue()}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

On `handleChange` function i am just pushing the value to an object needed for rest of the work first then i am modifying the `dropdownArray` . The Array List of dropdown should filter based on the selection.

Below is my `handleChange` function which the dropdown values are filtered.

```
handleChange(name, value){
    switch(name){
        case '1' :
            this.state.selectedDropdownArray["0"] = value === "select" ? null : value
        break;
        case '2' :
            this.state.selectedDropdownArray["1"] = value === "select" ? null : value
        break;
        case '3'
        ...
        ...
    }

    let filter = Object.values(this.state.selectedDropdownArray);
    let difference = this.state.dropdownArray.filter(x => !filter.includes(x));

}
```

If 1st dropdown with value `1` is selected, the `difference` has now the filtered array `[2,3,4,5]` which i can `setState` to `dropdownArray`.

But the 1st dropdown list does not have `1` to display in this select, since the array is already filtered.

What is the valid approach to achieve this problem to have unique selection for each 4 select dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: Define selected as array:

```
this.state = {
  selectedDropdownArray: [],
  dropdownArray: ['select','1','2','3','4','5']
}
```

If it is not required for other reasons - it won't be necessary to use `Object.values()` later in filtering.

2nd: Avoid binding in render, it's better to bind `this.handleChange` in constructor or use arrow syntax - read react docs about handling events, passing parameters...

3rd: You can use options filtering for each instance separately, sth like:

```
<SelectDropdown
  options={this.state.dropdownArray.filter(x => !this.state.selectedDropdownArray.includes(x) || x===this.state.selectedDropdownArray[0])}
  value={this.state.selectedDropdownArray[0] || ''}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Of course use next indexes for next `<SelectDropdown/>` instances ;)

Comment: I used `selected ` as object just to avoid `.push` which will have multiple entires.

Comment: Do you mean array.push with same key if exists

Comment: No need to use `push` - just use indexed array access - try in console: `var arr=[]; arr[3]=true; console.log(arr); arr[3]='whatever'; console.log(arr);`

Comment: Got it.. I implemented successfully. Thanks man for your time.